# How can I measure the queuing time of a process (CPU intensive) before it gets executed?

Tags: linux

Actually I am trying to run some experiments where i need to run benchmarks under heavy load. Starting from CPU load, I schedule a sysbench daemon that generates 1000 primes. I set its priority to low so that it only runs once the cpu is not busy with other tasks so as to reduce its impact on the regular workload. Since the priority of the process is set to Low, the process keeps waiting in the queue until it finds a free cpu core to run on. The problem is that its result shows the execution time including the wait period (in the queue) which renders the result invalid.

Is there some way that I could actually calculate the wait period and subtract it from the result to get a valid result?

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239118/cpu-contention-wait-time-for-a-process-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for your reply but thats not what i am looking for. Actually I figured it out just a while ago that /proc/<pid>/stat provides metrics  "utime" and "stime" which solve my problem!